# process count discrepancy for Linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

The following is a script:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo ------------------------
date
OCCURANCE=`ps -ef|grep "test.sh" | grep -vc grep`
ps -ef|grep "test.sh" | grep -vc grep
ps -ef|grep "test.sh" | grep -v grep
echo $OCCURANCE
```

The Output in Linux:

```
------------------------
Mon Apr 29 10:36:38 GMT 2013
1
tmon 15565  7469  0 10:36 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./test.sh
2
```

The Output in SunOS:

```
------------------------
Monday, April 29, 2013 10:33:47 AM GMT
1
tmon 21248 17305   0 10:33:48 pts/7       0:00 /bin/sh ./test.sh
1
```

As per the code, the 2 numeric values should be same.
But, why is it true for SunOS and false for Linux?

Comment: To format your code, avoid `<br>` and use 4 spaces in front of the lines. Also, select it and Ctrl+K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, the subshell spawned by the backticks has an entry in the output of `ps` which contains the string `test.sh`.  On Sun, it does not.

Comment: Now, in my test, the cmd `ps -ef|grep "test.sh" | grep -v grep` gave me only one line, ie, `tmon 15565  7469  0 10:36 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./test.sh`, which is 1 line only.
But the value for `OCCURANCE` is `2`. 
Why is it so???

Comment: Because the subshell spawned by the backticks has an entry in the output of `ps`.  So the `ps` run inside the backticks prints a count of 2.

Answer (score 1):

`/bin/sh` on your Linux system is likely a symbolic link to `bash`.  Your script is launching a subshell resulting in another process.

On the other hand, subshells in `ksh` do not mandate a separate process.  Try running your code in `ksh`, and you'll see the expected output.

Again, the shell being used on SunOS isn't likely to be `bash`.  If you attempt to use `bash` on Solaris, you'll notice a similar behaviour as on Linux.

Comment: Now, in my test, the cmd `ps -ef|grep "test.sh" | grep -v grep` gave me only one line, ie, `tmon 15565  7469  0 10:36 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./test.sh`, which is 1 line only.
But the value for `OCCURANCE` is `2`. 
Why is it so???